# Viewing extensions' proxy settings in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, extension

How do I view proxy settings of a Chrome extension? When I go to `Settings - Network`, it says:

```
Your network proxy settings are being managed by an extension.
```

Please let me know if the question is unclear, Thanks!

Comment: Is this a general question about how to find the settings an extension is using, or specific to your circumstances? Country-restriction bypassing extensions tend to set proxy settings; if your problem can be resolved by deactivating that extension, go for it :)

Comment: I really like how [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skyzip-proxy/hbgknjagaclofapkgkeapamhmglnbphi) bypasses China's firewall on Facebook, Twitter, Google, and Dropbox, and I'm interested in using it system-wide if possible. (Right now this chrome extension is only developed for chrome to my knowledge. I suspect by knowing its proxy settings, I would be able to let the dropbox app connect to it too.)